# angular ngView route change touch screen IE

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, touch

I'm using 1.2.14 and am testing in IE 11. I'm using an ngView with various routes and template definitions. when using the mouse to click on links everything is working and angular is intercepting, loading the template, etc. When using the touchscreen to touch a link I believe the interceptor is being bypassed and a direct request to the resource is being made to the server.

I'm developing and testing on windows 8.1 with touch using IE 11. I have not tested on anything else yet.

Answer (score 0):

I thought IE 11 was the culprit and that the below CSS would fix the issue.  This ended up not being true after further testing.

Style:
  html { 
    -ms-touch-action: none; /* Direct all pointer events to JavaScript code. */
  }
MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673557(v=vs.85).aspx

I used this approach too quickly... the above will also disable pinch and swipe events which is not the desired behavior.  I'm switching from anchors with ng-href to anchors / buttons with ng-click directives to get past this.